# how can I edit the spark mllib source code locally in Intelij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am studying spark mllib source codes in Intellij IDEA, using mllib as external libraries. I am not able to edit the source code. How can I achieve this? (they seem read-only). How can I make all source code local in Intellij IDEA, and edit them?
I just want to be able to edit the source code. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Fork [GitHub repository](https://github.com/apache/spark), import to your favorite IDE, make changes, [build](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html).

Comment: can you please provide a bit more detail? I am new to all of this and need some guidance. Thanks you very much.

Comment: I cloned the spark repository into Intellij IDEA and can open the source code files. How can I proceed to run an example (say kmeans)?  Please help. Thanks

Comment: @eugenerory, have you solved your problem?

Comment: yes, you go to project structure -> libraries ->java and add the  folder for MLLIB as a library. then go to project structure -> module -> dependencies  and check the box for the library you just added. hit ok. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle read-only attribute of a file. Do one of the following:

1. On the main menu, choose File | Make File Read-Only, or File | Make File Writable.
2. Click the lock icon in the Status bar.

If it not work, please check if you are editing a reverse engineered file.